# dotenv not working with serverless/webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, environment-variables, serverless-framework

EDIT: If I log out `dotenv.config()` I get an error of : `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myPathToApplication/.webpack/test/.env'`

I am bundling my serverless handler in order to use es6/es7 code. I have some `env` variables that I am trying to use as well. The problem is it seems that `dotenv` is not working when I bundle the handler.

For example one of the utils I am using is connecting `mongoose` to my application. In here I store the `DB_URI` as an env variable.  import envdotjs from 'envdotjs';

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
require('dotenv').config();
let isConnected;

const connectToDatabase = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('=> using existing database connection');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  console.log('=> using new database connection');
  return mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI).then(db => {
    isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
  });
};

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase
};
```

However the `DB_URI` is undefined and the code breaks.

Here is my webpack:

```
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I am running this in order to use es6/7 on serverless handler which is working just fine. But the env variables are breaking. I also tried using a module called `envdotjs` and got the same results that the env variables are undefined so I don't think this is a problem with `dotenv`.

Comment: Worse case you can move your environment variable sunder `provider 
 > environment` in your serverless configuration. Also you could try [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)

Comment: Bout to post an answer for dotenv-webpack

Answer (score 1):

I found a package `dotenv-webpack` also recommended by @apokryfos. Just require it in `const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')` and include it in the `webpack.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
...
  plugins: [new Dotenv()]
}
```

Just include your `.env` in the root with your `webpack.config.js` and you can declare your `process.env.` anywhere you need to with no other configuration.